# Recursive Backtracking to Solve suduko

Tags: python, recursion, backtracking

I'm trying to use recursion to solve a suduko puzzle in the form of a numpy array:
Like So:

```
[[5 3 0 0 7 0 0 0 0]
 [6 0 0 1 9 5 0 0 0]
 [0 9 8 0 0 0 0 6 0]
 [8 0 0 0 6 0 0 0 3]
 [4 0 0 8 0 3 0 0 1]
 [7 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 6]
 [0 6 0 0 0 0 2 8 0]
 [0 0 0 4 1 9 0 0 5]
 [0 0 0 0 8 0 0 7 9]]
```

I've made a verification function like so:

```
def possible(y, x, n):
    ylim = (y//3)*3
    xlim = (x//3)*3 

    ln = board[ylim:ylim+3, xlim:xlim+3].flatten().tolist()

    for i in ln:
        if i==n:
            return False

    vert = board[y].tolist()

    for i in vert:
        if i==n:
            return False

    horz = board[x].tolist()

    for i in horz:
        if i==n:
            return False   

    return True
```

And finally the "Solve" function:

```
def solve(board):

    for index, value in np.ndenumerate(board):
        y, x = index

        if value == 0:

            for n in range(1, 10):
                if (possible(y, x, n)):
                    board[y][x]=n
                    solve(board)                    
                    board[y][x] = 0

            return 
    print(board)
```

However this does not seem to return anything and the program outputs a blank line.

Comment: Indeed, `solve()` does not return anything.  What are you expecting it to return?

Comment: Also, show us the top-level code that defines `board` and calls `solve()`.

Comment: `vert = board[y].tolist()` probably doesn't do what you think it does. Try `vert = board[:, y]`. Also, there is no need for a conversion to Python lists and a loop. `if n in board[ylim:ylim+3, xlim:xlim+3]` and `if n in board[:, y]` and `if n in board[x]` are enough. In fact, this whole function can be simplified into just a few lines!

Comment: @JohnGordon its printing out the modified board. It doesnt need to "return" anything

Comment: Then what did you mean by saying "this does not seem to return anything"?  If it doesn't need to return anything, then why were you seemingly surprised when it did not, in fact, not return anything?